# How to put a value to a positional argument when nothing written?

Tags: python-3.x, class, module

I'm creating a little module for a game and I encountered the next problem:

```
class Visuals:
    def TypeWriter(str, new_line):
    #--- This part will define a new line, making
    #--- lines will auto separate each other.
        if new_line == None:
            new_line = True
        
        if new_line == True:
            print("\n")
        else:
            pass
        
        for char in str:
            time.sleep(0.07)
            sys.stdout.write(char)
            sys.stdout.flush()
Visuals.TypeWriter('This is a text.')
Visuals.TypeWriter('This is another text.')
```

Now the thing is that obviously I want, in order to be efficient, to not have to write the 'new_line= True' every time I call the function but the lines 5 and 6 with the None don't work as expected, what should I do to make it be True by default if I don't specify the state of 'new_line'? I use Python 3.

Comment: unrelated: `if new_line is None` not == .. and also `if new_line:` - not  == True: and also : do not use str as variable - that shadows the str() function

Comment: `def TypeWriter(str, new_line = None): if new_line is None: new_line = True`

Answer (score 0):

You should use a keyword argument for this.

```
def TypeWriter(string, new_line=True):
    ...
```

The value of `new_line` will always be `True`, unless you specify otherwise:

```
TypeWriter("str", new_line=False)
```